# 360 renders have artifacts on glossy objects

Tags: artifacts

I have made a scene with an ocean. I used glossy shader as its material. When I render it I found weird artifacts at the bottom of the 360 render. 
So I made a new blend file to test if the issue is with using the gloss shader or if the issue is with 360 renders. 
Using a sphere with a Voronoi texture as displacement. I used a glossy shader on it. And yes the issue seems to be that reflections get weird when you do a 360 render(paranomic).

Please help me understand what the problem is.

Edit:
Unfortunately, the render is above 4k. so it's not possible to upload it here and if I downgrade it to low res im pretty sure u won't be able to see the artifact.
So here: https://youtu.be/C7360TeoJ8I I uploaded it on youtube. 
Is it possible to upload a blend file here?

Comment: Could you show the renderings?

Comment: made the edit. Hope it helped a bit to understand the question. I'll see if there is a way to upload the blend file.

Comment: @KarmaKast use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload a file, then add the resulting link as part of your question.